# Does it give performance or accessibility benefit when one prefer to use JavaScript over C# for writing a Windows8 app?

Tags: c#, javascript, performance, windows-8

If one will have an option to select between JavaScript (With HTML) and C# (With XAML) for writing a Windows 8 app which one should he/she prefer ? Does it give  any performance benefit or Is C# has greater accessibility to Windows8 API and system calls ?

Comment: It depends on what are you building.Secondly some library when you are calling from javascript will go extra step in the JS.
IT is better if you will give a bit detail about what are you doing

Comment: @KamranShahid , thanks for your reply. I haven't started the development of app. But before starting my work I just want to ensure that my language of selection will have the maximum access to Windows-8 API ,so that any future upgrade or addition will not force me to switch the language hence forcing me to write everything again.

Comment: Hmmm, I know it would be hard to share what sort of the application you are making as it's the idea that is the most important one in these app development world.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there was some confusion about the OP. We're talking about developing apps for Windows 8. You can use multiple language stacks to target Windows 8. You can use XAML/C#, XAML/C++, DirectX/C++, or HTML/JavaScript. The question was in regard to which of the two most popular stacks - XAML/C# and HTML/JavaScript - has better performance and better access to the Windows API.

I'm a Developer Evangelist at Microsoft and this is the most frequently asked question I get. I have a post at [codefoster.com/Which-Windows-8-Language-Stack-Should-I-Choose](http://codefoster.com/Which-Windows-8-Language-Stack-Should-I-Choose) that touches part of the question but not all.

First, regarding access to the Windows API (WinRT), all language stacks are identical. The entire WinRT object space is actually projected into the different languages, so in any language you can call into the Windoww API and they always start with "Windows.".

The projections follow the conventions of each of the languages they're projected into as well, so in C# you might call Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello World").ShowAsync(), whereas in JavaScript you would call Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello World").showAsync(). Similarly, each language uses its own conventions for handling async. In C#, you would use the async/await pattern, but in JavaScript you would use the promise pattern.

Next, on the matter of performance. There are going to be differences between the language stacks due to the natural and drastic differences between the languages. The important thing to know is that for all built in controls and scenarios, all language stacks are designed to meet a *minimum* performance threshold. Honestly, I don't think you need to worry about any of the language stacks falling behind in performance for you unless you've got some really interesting stuff going on in which case you should be specific about what it is.

Each of the language stacks has its own strengths and weaknesses as well. If you're using C# you have a good set of the .NET framework with is extremely familiar to many people. It's also a very well designed and expressive language. Additionally, XAML is a very powerful UI language. If you're using JavaScript then you have code in common with the rest of the vast internet and can share a lot of code. You can find JavaScript libraries to do just about anything you want and you can use any of those in your Windows 8 app. If you are using C++ then you have access to existing C and C++ components and access to DirectX for making 3D apps.

Keep in mind that you can make hybrid apps where you use C# or C++ to create WinRT components and then you can consume those components in any of the language stacks - including JavaScript! So if you know C# and want to write your business logic in C#, you can do that and then just use that logic in your JavaScript app.

Finally, I think the two biggest factors in making the decision on which stack to choose are 1) the stack you have the most skill in already and 2) the stack you *enjoy* using. Those are important and might carry you through a project you would otherwise ditch.

I hope this helps make your decision. If you need any help making Windows 8 apps, I'm at [codefoster.com](http://codefoster.com).

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a scripting language to a native (compiled) language.

JS has very limited access to the system when compared to C#. But then again, depending on what you want to application to do, it could be the best choice.

Comment: I want my application to be scalable if required in future. If JS has limited access to system then it might be a problem. Before starting to write the app I want to ensure that my selection of language will let me have the access to the most of the functionality in Windows-8.

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to use C#. Js is quite limited in both function and efficiency, compared to native languages.

Comment: JS is not so limited as Cerbrus is saying. It does not have limited access to the WinRT API. There is _just about_ nothing you can do in C# that you can't do in JS, and there are some things JS can do that C# can't. @Cerbrus, please check your facts.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that JS has more functionality than native code. Do you have some specific examples, @JeremyFoster?